# What is the grammatical function of "circumstances as they are" in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-structure, functions

I find this sentence in an online article strange and even jarring for several reasons.

> With limited provisions, he awaits reinforcements, but **circumstances as they are**, is believed lost to the wilds. ([source](https://www.thatmomentin.com/dances-with-wolves-kevin-costner-movie-moment/))

I am not quite sure what grammar function "circumstances as they are" takes. It seems there's missing components. I have never seen *things as they are* or *circumstances as they are* stand alone in a sentence like this (except in book titles). I would have written:

> With limited provisions, he awaits reinforcements, but **given circumstances as they are**, is believed lost to the wilds.

Am I correct in thinking the sentence is ungrammatical as it stands? If I am wrong, what grammatical role does "circumstances as they are" take? Is it adverbial?

Comment: It's a verbless clause and common enough in informal speech.  In full, it would be "circumstances being as/what they are".

Comment: @BillJ Yes, this seems like the definitive answer.  I'll add the observation that OP is correct that the phrase *as a whole* functions as an *adverb* (it modifies 'is believed') with or without the missing form of 'to be.'  Have you considered converting your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it’s technically a prepositional phrase. There’s an understood “with” here: “...he awaits reinforcements, but *with* circumstances as they are...”
That’s just one of those technically-improper-if-you-want-to-split-hairs-but-people-say-it-like-that-anyway phrases. With your edit, the “given” seems to be acting as an adjective and doesn’t affect the grammatical structure. Either the original or way is fine.